# How to find the date of creation or first use of each channel in MQ Explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

We have have 5 channels in our IBM MQ Explorer for the App.To.REG queue manager.
I want to find the date of creation or first use of each channel.
I have tried both `display channel` and `display chstatus` command but it didn't gave the required details.

Comment: If these are SENDER channels then you can some times infer the creation date based on the creation date of the associated XMITQ which is tracked by MQ.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an MQ Configuration and/or Monitoring tool for that type of information.  Also, you will need to turn on the queue manager's Configuration Events.  The DIS CHL() command will only give you the last altered date & time.